# React on button click events using Wixstdba bootstrapper

Tags: wix

we are using the wixstdba bootstrapper for our setup.
We now want to do some installation tracking: we want to know at which step in the setup the user is cancelling. We'd like to send a http request to our servers with some information.
Is it possible to react on button click events - in that special case the Cancel button? Or do you know some better solution to send an http request during canceling?
As I mentioned, we are using wixstdba bootstrapper because it was easy to create and customize a setup. We are now at the point where stuff gets more complicated and therefore thinking about creating our own bootstrapper application - but we'd like to avoid this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create your own `BootstrapperApplication` to support that scenario. Fortunately, because you get complete control over the user experience in the `BootstrapperApplication` adding the above functionality will simply be a matter of writing the code. Unfortunately, it does mean writing more code to own the overall experience.

Comment: Is it possible to run a custom action when the setup was canceled? Maybe by detecting a rollback?

Comment: Custom actions are part of the Windows Installer. Burn doesn't have custom actions. In WiX v3.8 there are BA Functions supported by wixstdba that allow you to respond to OnDetect and OnPlan but nothing to respond during apply. Might be something to investigate enhancing if you are interested.

Comment: What's the purpose of having a Button element in the theme schema if we cannot handle the click event?

Comment: @Alex Buttons are available in the theme schema so applications can have buttons on their UI. The theme file declares the UI's display not how it is processed.